# Multi-threaded image processing with openCV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, python-multithreading

I am quite new to python and have problems to parallize a part of my algorithm.
Consider an input image thats need to be threshold in a certain way on pixel level. Since the algorithm only considers a specific area to calculate the threshold values, I'd like to run each chunk of the image in a seperate thread/process. And this is where I am stuck. I could not find a way that these threads work on the same image or how I can merge the results into a new image.
Since I am usually from the java world I usually fighting the problem that I not want to interfere in other Thread. Therefore I just tried to pass each process the image.

```
def thresholding(img):
    stepSize = int(img.shape[0] / 10)
    futures = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
        for y in range(0, img.shape[0], stepSize):
            for x in range(0, img.shape[1], stepSize):
                futures.append(e.submit(thresholdThread, y, x, img))
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
    return img


def thresholdThread(y, x, img):
    window_size = int(img.shape[0] / 10)
    window_shape = (window_size, window_size)
    window = img[y:y + window_shape[1], x:x + window_shape[0]]
    upper_bound, lower_bound, avg = getThresholdBounds(window, 0.6)

    for y_2 in range(0, window.shape[0]):
        for x_2 in range(0, window.shape[1]):
            tmp = img[y + y_2, x + x_2]
            img[y + y_2, x + x_2] = tmp if (tmp >= upper_bound or tmp <= lower_bound) else avg
    return str(avg)
```

As far as I understand python this does not work, because each process gets its own copy of `img`. But since img is of type ndarray of floats from numpy I have no idea if and how I could use shared object as descibed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

FYI: I am using python 3.6.9. I do know that 3.7 is released, but installing everthing again so I can use spyder and openCV is not so easy.

Comment: Are you asking how to put all the pieces back together after they have been processed?

Comment: It woud be a solution I can live with. In my opinion a shared object on which each process would work on, would be a nicer solution, but merging the results in an efficient way is fine with me.

Comment: How big is the image? Why do you need to process the patches in parallel? Can you include `getThresholdBounds`?

Comment: The images are ~2MB, but can vary. One example has the size of 4864x3456 pixels. And I want to run this skript inside docker images which have no high CPU capacity, but up to 4 cores. Therefore parallelism would be a good way to speed things up. And ```getThresholdBounds``` may differ in my experiments. But basically I take the ```0.6 * maxValueOfWindow``` for the upper bound and vice verser on the lower bound.

Comment: You are *thresholding* **non-overlapping** square patches? The patch shape is based on the first dimension of the array? the bottom and right patches may be smaller than the others? Greyscale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not taking advantage of any of Numpy's vectorization techniques which can decrease processing time significantly. I'm assuming this is why you want to multiprocess operations on windows/chunks of the image(s) - I don't know what Docker is so I don't know whether that is a factor in your multiprocess approach.

Here is a vectorized solution with the caveat that it possibly excludes bottom and right edge *pixels* from the operations.  If that is not acceptable no need to read any further.

The size of the right and bottom edge *windows* in **your** example are, more likely than not, different than the other windows. Looks like you arbitrarily chose a factor of ten to chunk up your image - if ten was an arbitrary choice, you can optimize the bottom and right edge deltas easily - I'll post that function at the end of the answer.

The image needs to be *reshaped* into patches to vectorize the operations . I've used an [`sklearn` function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e85a6d1f/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L244) `sklearn.feature_extraction.image._extract_patches` because it is convenient and allows creation of non-overlapping patches (which appears to be what you want). Notice the underscore prefix - this used to be an *exposed* function, `image.extract_patches`, but that has been deprecated. The function uses `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` - it might be possible to just `reshape` the array but I haven't tried that.

Setup

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
img = np.arange(4864*3546*3).reshape(4864,3546,3)
# all shape dimensions in the following example derived from img's shape
```

Define the patch size (see `opt_size` below) and *reshape* the image.

```
hsize, h_remainder, h_windows = opt_size(img.shape[0])
wsize, w_remainder, w_windows = opt_size(img.shape[1])

# rgb - not designed for rgba
if img.ndim == 3:
    patch_shape = (hsize,wsize,img.shape[-1])
else:
    patch_shape = (hsize,wsize)

patches = image._extract_patches(img,patch_shape=patch_shape,
                                 extraction_step=patch_shape)
patches = patches.squeeze()
```

`patches` is a view of the original array changes to it will be seen in the original. Its shape is `(8, 9, 608, 394, 3)` There are `8x9`, `(608,394,3)` windows/patches.

Find the upper and lower bounds of each patch; compare each pixel to the bounds for its patch; extract the indices for each pixel that is between its bounds and needs to be changed.

```
lower = patches.min((2,3)) * .6
lower = lower[...,None,None,:]
upper = patches.max((2,3)) * .6
upper = upper[...,None,None,:]
indices = np.logical_and(patches > lower, patches < upper).nonzero()
```

Find the mean of each patch then change the required pixel values,

```
avg = patches.mean((2,3))    # shape (8,9,3)
patches[indices] = avg[indices[0],indices[1],indices[-1]]
```

---

Function that puts it all together

```
def g(img, opt_shape=False):
    original_shape = img.shape

    # determine patch shape   
    if opt_shape:
        hsize, h_remainder, h_windows = opt_size(img.shape[0])
        wsize, w_remainder, w_windows = opt_size(img.shape[1])
    else:
        patch_size = img.shape[0] // 10
        hsize, wsize = patch_size,patch_size

    # constraint checking here(?) for
    #     number of windows,
    #     orphaned pixels

    if img.ndim == 3:
        patch_shape = (hsize,wsize,img.shape[-1])
    else:
        patch_shape = (hsize,wsize)

    patches = image._extract_patches(img,patch_shape=patch_shape,
                                     extraction_step=patch_shape)
    #squeeze??
    patches = patches.squeeze()

    #assume color (h,w,3)
    lower = patches.min((2,3)) * .6
    lower = lower[...,None,None,:]
    upper = patches.max((2,3)) * .6
    upper = upper[...,None,None,:]
    indices = np.logical_and(patches > lower, patches < upper).nonzero()

    avg = patches.mean((2,3))
##    del lower, upper, mask
    patches[indices] = avg[indices[0],indices[1],indices[-1]]
```

---

```
def opt_size(size):
    '''Maximize number of windows, minimize loss at the edge

    size -> int
       Number of "windows" constrained to 4-10
       Returns (int,int,int)
           size in pixels,
           loss in pixels,
           number of windows
    '''

    size = [(divmod(size,n),n) for n in range(4,11)]
    n_windows = 0
    remainder = 99
    patch_size = 0
    for ((p,r),n) in size:
        if r <= remainder and n > n_windows:
            remainder = r
            n_windows = n
            patch_size = p
    return patch_size, remainder, n_windows
```

---

Tested against your *naïve* process - I hope I executed it correctly. About a 35x improvement on the 4864x3546 color *image*.  There are probably further optimizations maybe some wizards will comment.

Test using your chunk factor of ten:

```
#yours
def f(img):
    window_size = int(img.shape[0] / 10)
    window_shape = (window_size, window_size)

    for y in range(0, img.shape[0], window_size):
        for x in range(0, img.shape[1], window_size):

            window = img[y:y + window_shape[1], x:x + window_shape[0]]
            upper_bound = window.max((0,1)) * .6
            lower_bound = window.min((0,1)) * .6
            avg = window.mean((0,1))

            for y_2 in range(0, window.shape[0]):
                for x_2 in range(0, window.shape[1]):
                    tmp = img[y + y_2, x + x_2]
                    indices = np.logical_and(tmp < upper_bound,tmp > lower_bound)
                    tmp[indices] = avg[indices]


img0 = np.arange(4864*3546*3).reshape(4864,3546,3)
#get everything the same shape
size = img0.shape[0] // 10
h,w = size*10, size * (img0.shape[1]//size)
img1 = img0[:h,:w].copy()
img2 = img1.copy()

assert np.all(np.logical_and(img1==img2,img2==img0[:h,:w]))
f(img1)    # ~44 seconds
g(img2)    # ~1.2 seconds
assert(np.all(img1==img2))
if not np.all(img2==img0[:h,:w]):
    pass
else:
    raise Exception('did not change')
```

---

`indices` is an [index array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays).  It is a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension. `indices[0][0],indices[1][0],indices[2][0]` would be the index for one *element* in a 3d array. The complete tuple can be used to index multiple elements of an array.

```
>>> indices
(array([1, 0, 2]), array([1, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1]))
>>> list(zip(*indices))
[(1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1), (2, 0, 1)]
>>> arr = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> arr[1,1,1], arr[0,0,1],arr[2,0,2]
(13, 1, 20)
>>> arr[indices]
array([13,  1, 19])

# arr[indices] <-> np.array([arr[1,1,1],arr[0,0,1],arr[2,0,1]])
```

`np.logical_and(patches > lower, patches < upper)` returns a boolean array and [`nonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) returns the indices of all the elements with a value of `True`.

Comment: I had to adapt your answer a little, since I am actually working on response map of the image. Therefore it is a simple ndarray of floats and not RGB values. 
But after that it was much faster and makes the parallism unnessary. So thanks you very much.
But on the other hand I am still curious if you can work in a image from different processes. Is it really that unusual for python to work on shared memory?

Comment: I didn't try it on a 2d array. You probably had to change `lower[...,None,None,:]`, `upper[...,None,None,:]`, and `avg[indices[0],indices[1],indices[-1]]`.??  Probably could *automate* that instead of hard coding.  I'm curious whterh the losses at the edges affect your process.

Comment: Yeah, after figuring out what you did there, I changed exactly those lines. I put ```None``` at the end and removed ```indices[-1]```.
But it would be nice if you could explain the result of ```np.logical_and(patches > lower, patches < upper).nonzero()```. I am not sure about the layout of ```indices```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html